# I need to connect to a live open source data base and want to record data if a certain key is present and ignore all other data

Tags: python, json

JSON format:

```
[{"SH_MSG": {"time": "1657291114000", "area_id": "D1", "address": "54", "msg_type": "SH", "data": "8CFB0B00"}}, {"SF_MSG": {"time": "1657291114000", "area_id": "D2", "address": "0A", "msg_type": "SF", "data": "1F"}}, ...}][...]
```

I want to record all data that has a `CA_MSG` tag at the start.

I am using stomp to obtain messages.

```
msg = json.loads(frame.body)
```

`msg` is a list such that:

```
msg = [{'SF_MSG': {'...'}}, ...]
```

I am trying:

```
for m in msg:
    new_msg = []
    if m.keys() == 'CA_MSG':
         new_msg.append(m)
```

But this is just returning `[]` every time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting there in the end by skipping out the for loops for a list comprehension:

```
CA_MSGS = [msg['CA_MSG'] for msg in message if 'CA_MSG' in list(msg.keys())]
```

Answer (score -1):

1. dict.keys() returns a list object for python version 2,
2. dict.keys() returns a dict_keys object for python version 3,

it can never be a True if you check the list/dict_keys object with a string object

```
if m.keys() == 'CA_MSG': # False all the time

# probably this is what you are looking for

# python 2
if m.keys().count('CA_MSG') > 0:

# python 3 change the dict_keys to a set probably good performance
if 'CA_MSG' in set(m.keys()):
```

Comment: Is there a different way to apply this requirement?

Comment: But m.keys() is a dict_keys() class and not a list so .count() will not work? Thank you for the advice so far by the way

Comment: yeah there is a diff between python versions, I changed the code